# Why are previous array values being carried over in new loop?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code to populate checkbox fields in a gravity form. I have an array of `field_ids` I'm looping through with a foreach loop. `$arr = array(5, 6, 7, 8, 9);` I then have a second foreach loop with a query which is pulling data from the database.

The code is working however, each subsequent `field_id` is showing the results for that field_id and the previous ones. e.g `field_id=6` is showing a list of checkbox fields for `field_id=5` and `field_id=6`. `field_id= 7` is showing a list of checkbox fields for `field_id=5`, `field_id=6` and `field_id=7` etc.

```
function populate_checkboxes( $form ){

    foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field )  {
        $arr = array(5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

        foreach($arr as $field_id){
          global $wpdb;
          $query = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT sefer FROM bulk_import where field_id_select_items = {$field_id}" );
          foreach($query as $sefer){

            if ( $field->id != $field_id ) {continue;}
            $choices[] = array( 'text' => 'Select All', 'value' => 'Select_all' ); 
            $inputs[] = array( 'label' => 'Select All', 'id' => '1'); 
            //get all $sefer values
            $posts = get_posts(array(
            'post_type'=> array('learning_item'),   'suppress_filters' => 0, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'order' => 'asc', 
            'meta_query' => array(  
                array( 'key' => 'taken',   'value' => '0'),
                array('key' => 'torah', 'value' => $sefer -> sefer)
            ),
            ));

            $input_id = 2;
            foreach( $posts as $post ) {
                //skipping index that are multiples of 10 (multiples of 10 create problems as the input IDs)
                if ( $input_id % 10 == 0 ) {$input_id++;}
                $choices[] = array( 'text' => $post->post_title, 'value' => $post->post_title );
                $inputs[] = array( 'label' => $post->post_title, 'id' => "{$field_id}.{$input_id}" );

                $input_id++;
            }

            $field->choices = $choices; 
            $field->inputs = $inputs; 

          }
            //reset query here? 
             wp_reset_query();
        }

    }
    return $form;}
```

Do I need to set a variable to empty somewhere in the array? Why is there being a carry through of data? How do I show only values connected to the specific `field_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of each loop you need to reset the arrays where your building up the values.  It could be something like...

```
  foreach($query as $sefer){
        $choices = array();
        $inputs = array();

        if ( $field->id != $field_id ) {continue;}
```

Unless you reset them, they still have the values from the previous loop.